# Remove all files except for last file of each month

Tags: bash, rm

Consider a directory with MySQL backup files with timestamps as part of the filename:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35856184 Nov 16 16:00 db_2013-11-16_1600.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35856915 Nov 16 17:00 db_2013-11-16_1700.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35857565 Nov 16 18:00 db_2013-11-16_1800.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35858254 Nov 16 19:00 db_2013-11-16_1900.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35860276 Nov 16 20:00 db_2013-11-16_2000.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35861583 Nov 16 21:00 db_2013-11-16_2100.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35863630 Nov 16 22:00 db_2013-11-16_2200.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35864868 Nov 16 23:00 db_2013-11-16_2300.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35866095 Nov 17 00:00 db_2013-11-17_0000.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35887731 Nov 17 01:00 db_2013-11-17_0100.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35888871 Nov 17 02:00 db_2013-11-17_0200.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35888871 Nov 17 03:00 db_2013-11-17_0300.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 35889319 Nov 17 04:00 db_2013-11-17_0400.sql
```

These actually go on since September 2012! I need to delete all backups except for the last backup of each month. That is, these files should be left:

```
db_2012-09-30_2300.sql
db_2012-10-31_2300.sql
db_2012-11-30_2300.sql
db_2012-12-31_2300.sql
db_2013-01-31_2300.sql
db_2013-02-28_2300.sql
db_2013-03-31_2300.sql
db_2013-04-30_2300.sql
db_2013-05-30_2300.sql
db_2013-06-30_2300.sql
db_2013-07-31_2300.sql
db_2013-08-31_2300.sql
db_2013-09-30_2300.sql
db_2013-10-31_2300.sql
db_2013-11-20_0700.sql # Because this month has not finished yet!
```

I could write a Bash/Python script to create lists of each month, remove the last item from the list and then delete one-by-one the remaining files. Alternatively, the script could move the last files from each month to a temp directory, remove everything, then put the files back.

*However* I wonder if there is some way to simply tell `rm` (or rm with `find` and `awk` and `sort`) to ignore the last file of the month. **Is there such a magic spell?**

I do recognise that life would be easier if I could just save *the first file* from each month (which would be only a 1 hour difference from saving the *last* file from each month) but that is not acceptable to others in the organization who fail to see that this essentially provides the same protection.

Comment: `sort -r | uniq -w11` gets you a list of the files you want to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the file zz containing the list of file names, this works, so just replace cat zz.

```
cat zz | grep -vF -f <(cat zz|sort -r|uniq -w11)
```

e.g.
    echo *.sql | grep -vF -f <( echo *.sql | sort -r | uniq -w11 ) | xargs rm

As is, it won't work if spaces in file names, and very fragile to filename length.

Comment: Thank you Richard. Is the goal to show the names of the files to keep? On my Ubuntu 12.10 test system it is showing all the files in `zz`, just like `cat zz` alone would do. I do see where you are going with `sort` and `uniq` though, and that should give me some headway to run with. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not there yet, but this tip gets me a list of the files to keep and I can work from there. Thanks!

Comment: The `<(…)` is to get a list of files to keep. `grep -v` removes these names.

Answer (score 1):

A quick ugly brute force attempt in a script (could be done in one line, but need two for loops so it's kind of ugly in one line)

```
#! /bin/bash

for year in {2012..2013}
do
   for month in {01..12}
   do
      ls db_"$year"-"$month"*.sql 2>/dev/null | sort -r | tail -n +2 | xargs rm -f
   done
done
```

This of course assumes no special characters/whitespace in the file names, which seems to be your case.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I like the Bash loop, though I was hoping for something that would automatically figure that bit out.

Answer (score 1):

Using [ricchard's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4778/richard) idea removing all except last in month:

```
rm -f `ls *.sql | sort | uniq w11 -D -u`
```

To view what will be deleted:

```
ls *.sql | sort | uniq w11 -D -u
```

Answer (score -3):

I would use find for this,

something along the lines of `find "path" -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;`

that -mtime +30 signifies 30 days but that can be changed easily to suite your needs.

**edit**
alternatively you could set up a cron task with the above script instead use mv to move it to a convenient location.

Comment: Perhaps I failed to convey the idea. I need the last file _for each month_, not all files in the last 30 days.

Comment: @dotancohen I do apologize, you can specify a time range with find but that starts to become rather cumbersome as you would need to start with -x weeks until now then -1month until -x weeks, 
something like <code>find /directory -type f -mtime -10 -mtime +5 </code>

Comment: I am not looking for relative dates. Nor is this an operation that will need to be run periodically (cron). Thank you for trying, though.